# "gem install wkpdf" fails on osx-yosemite

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-yosemite

I get the following error:

```
% gem install wkpdf
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'wkpdf' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: wkpdf
```

I suspect it is related to `wkpdf` requiring `universal-darwin`, while the system has `universal-darwin-14`:

```
% gem list -r | grep wkpdf
plessl-wkpdf (0.3.5 universal-darwin)
wkpdf (0.6.11 universal-darwin)
% gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/pv/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-14
...
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: This is an opened issue on Github https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf/issues/49

Answer (score 0):

According to the author of `wkpdf`, Yosemite doesn't support RubyCocoa which `wkpdf` depends on and it is unlikely he will reimplement `wkpdf` in the near future.

I switched to using `wkhtmltopdf` instead; see http://wkhtmltopdf.org/.